# Pass loaded file location in RAM to function which need file name

Tags: python, tar, vtk, ram, paraview

I have a python VKT function `XMLPolyDataReader` which needs as argument a file location on the disk such as `XMLPolyDataReader('file.vtp')`.

Due due space issues I save all my `*.vtp` file as tar.gz.

Now I want to run some work which need some of the files located in the tar-file. For this I use the  tutorial from https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/tarfile-module to extract a single file such as : `file=file_obj.extractfile("sample.vtp")`.

Now `file` is loaded and located in the RAM. Is there a possibility to pass it directly to the `XMLPolyDataReader` function without writing it in a temporary file, which is then loaded again by the `XMLPolyDataReader` function?

Comment: That depends on the implementation of XMLPolyDataReader. It's not something I'm familiar with. What does the documentation say?

Comment: The XML Reader requires a file string location. No pointer possible. I'm looking if there is a possibility to get the RAM, pointer location as a virtual file, which is then called by the reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported.

You can use `.vtk` file format instead of `.vtp`, as the `vtkPolyDataReader` can [read from a string](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataReader.html#ad948a0d7d769617c991ec3e6e0a01065) (so basically from RAM)

*Edit*

Note that there is a work in progress to enable this kind of feature on more reader. See this [VTK forum post](https://discourse.vtk.org/t/new-customizable-way-to-load-data/9558)